# Cannot run 'npm run dev' after install laravel-mix-workbox

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I got an error when running 'npm run dev' after installing laravel-mix-workbox.

Here's the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fhXK.jpg)

> `[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Documents\Tolong Ya Allah\Digitani\node_modules\growly\lib\growly.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run and rebuild

```
npm i growly --save
```